# Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead using SciKit for image classification

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I am trying to train a Gaussian Naive Bayes model using `scikit-learn`. My database contains 656 images along with labels from a csv file. Below is the code I used to both import the images + labels as well as call/create the model.

```
from numpy.core.multiarray import ndarray
from os.path import join
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd

IMG_DIR = "/content/drive/MyDrive/allddi"
img_paths = list(sorted(glob(join(IMG_DIR, "*.png"))))
def read_img(path):
    img = IMG_DIR + "/" + path
    return img

imgs = [read_img(p) for p in img_paths]
df = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/ddi.images/ddi_metadata.csv", sep=",")
labels = list(sorted(df.sort_values(by="DDI_file")["malignant"].tolist()))

len(labels) == len(img_paths)
```

The code to create the model

```
from os import spread
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn import metrics

X = imgs
Y = np.array(labels)
model = GaussianNB()
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y)
model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

The error I keep getting is `expected a 2D array, got a 1D array`. I have tried various reshapes (-1, 1) and vice versa and nothing seems to get me through this error. I also have tried creating the Y variable using simply `Y = labels` but this also does not work.

Comment: You are not `actually reading` an image but just creating a `list of the image paths`. You can use [opencv](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-image-opencv-using-python/) to read an image as an array and then pass this array of images to your model.